# Proof $\frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}=\left| \frac{z_1}{z_2}\right|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, absolute-value

> Prove: $\frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}=\left| \frac{z_1}{z_2}\right|$

$$\frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}=\frac{|a+bi|}{|c+di|}=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{{a^2+b^2}}{{c^2+d^2}}}=\left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right| $$

I am not sure about the last part $$\sqrt{\frac{{a^2+b^2}}{{c^2+d^2}}}=\left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right| $$

Comment: Uhm, what are you asking exactly ? Your proof is ok if that's what you want to know.

Comment: @Victor edited, I am not sure about the last part

Comment: $\frac{z_1}{z_2}=\frac{a+bi}{c+di}=\frac{a(c-di)}{c^2+d^2}+\frac {bi(c-di)}{c^2+d^2}$. Expand this out and compute its modulus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To finish off,
$$
\frac{z_1}{z_2} = \frac{a+ib}{c+id} = \frac{(a+ib)(c-id)}{c^2+d^2} = \frac{(ac+bd)+i(bc-ad)}{c^2+d^2}
$$
so
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right| &= \frac{\sqrt{(ac+bd)^2+(bc-ad)^2}}{c^2+d^2}
\\ &= \frac{\sqrt{a^2c^2 + a^2d^2 + b^2c^2 + b^2d^2}}{c^2+d^2} = \frac{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}}{c^2+d^2} = \frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}.
\end{align}

(There are quicker ways to do it if you already know that $|zw| = |z|\,|w|$.)

Answer (score 1):

Write $z_1=a+di$ and $z_2=c+di$ then 
\begin{align*}
\frac{z_1}{z_2}&=\frac{a+bi}{c+di}\\
&\frac{a+bi}{c+di}\frac{c-di}{c-di}\\
&\frac{ac+bd+i(bc-ad)}{c^2+d^2}\\
\end{align*}
Then
 $$
|\frac{z_1}{z_2}|^2=\frac{(ac+bd)^2+(bc-ad)^2}{(c^2+d^2)^2}=\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2+d^2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

No, the last part is missing:
$|\frac{z_1}{z_2} | = \frac{|z_1 (c-di)|}{c^2+d^2} = \frac{|ac+bd+i(bc-ad)|}{|z_2|^2} = ...$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $z_1=x_1+iy_1$ and $z_2=x_2+iy_2$
$$
\begin{align}
\text{LHS}\Rightarrow\frac{\left|  z_1 \right| }{\left|  z_2 \right|}
&=\frac{\left|  x_1+iy_1 \right| }{\left|   x_2+iy_2 \right|}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2} }{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2}} \\
&=\frac{\sqrt{(x_1^2+y_1^2)(x_2^2+y_2^2)} }{x_2^2+y_2^2} \ (1)
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\text{RHS}\Rightarrow \left| \frac{z_1}{z_2} \right|
&=\left| \frac{x_1+iy_1}{x_2+iy_2} \right|\\ \\
&=\left| \frac{x_1+iy_1}{x_2+iy_2} \cdot \frac{x_2-iy_2}{x_2-iy_2} \right|\\ \\
&=\left| \frac{(x_1+iy_1)(x_2-iy_2)}{(x_2+iy_2)(x_2-iy_2)}\right|\\ \\
&=\left| \frac{(x_1x_2+y_1y_2)+i(-x_1y_2+x_2y_1)}{x_2^2+y_2^2}\right|\\ \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{(x_1x_2+y_1y_2)^2+(-x_1y_2+x_2y_1)^2}}{x_2^2+y_2^2}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{(x_1^2x_2^2+y_1^2y_2^2+2 x_1x_2y_1y_2)+(x_1^2x_2^2+y_1^2y_2^2-2 x_1x_2y_1y_2)}}{x_2^2+y_2^2}\\ \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{x_1^2x_2^2+y_1^2y_2^2+x_1^2x_2^2+y_1^2y_2^2}}{x_2^2+y_2^2}\\ \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\\ \\
x_1^2\Big(x_2^2+y_2^2\Big)+y_1^2\Big(x_2^2+y_2^2\Big)}}{x_2^2+y_2^2}\\ \\
&=\frac{\sqrt{(x_1^2+y_1^2)(x_2^2+y_2^2)} }{x_2^2+y_2^2} \ (2)
\end{align}
$$

See, (1) and (2) are equivalent.

Note: Fraction $\frac{\sqrt{(x_1^2+y_1^2)(x_2^2+y_2^2)} }{x_2^2+y_2^2}$ for Non-Zero values of $x_{1,2}$ and $y_{1,2}$ has answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can simplify things somewhat by breaking the problem into two parts $|z_1 z_2|=|z_1||z_2|$, and $|1/z|=1/|z|$.

For the first part, $|z_1 z_2|=\sqrt{z_1 z_2 \overline{z_1 z_2}}=\sqrt{z_1\overline{z_1}z_2\overline{z_2}}=\sqrt{z_1\overline{z_1}}\sqrt{z_2\overline{z_2}}=|z_1||z_2|$.

For the second part, $|1/z|=|\overline{z}/(z\overline z)|=|\overline{z}/|z|^2|=|z|/|z|^2$, where we have pulled out the real number $1/|z|^2$ from the expression and used the fact that $|z|=|\overline{z}|$.

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the denominator with conjugate then simplify.. You will get the answer